# NSUser defaults cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have been going back and forth on one certain part of my code. It works, but it doesn't seem right for some reason, as I believe there must be an easier/cleaner way to implement the `NSUserDefaults`. All of which are dates. I apologize that the code is so long. A lot of it is repetitive, and I want to learn the correct way to do this.

**In my header file:**

```
#define UserDefault [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
```

**In my Implementation file, under cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    ////////////////ADD EDIT GEAR ICON TO ACCESSORY CELL VIEW//////////////////
    UIImage *settingsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Edit Wheel"];
    UIButton *settingsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [settingsButton setImage:settingsImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [settingsButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 28.0, 28.0)];
    settingsButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    settingsButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
    [settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = settingsButton;

    /////////////DATE FORMATTER/////////////////////////
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *daysLeftLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];

    ///////////////////ADD IMAGE TO EACH CELL ACCORDING TO THUMBNAILS ARRAY//////////////////////
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    dateLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    dateLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 8./dateLabel.font.pointSize;;
    dateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    /////////////////////////////////NSUSER DEFAULTS////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSData *marriageDate = [UserDefault objectForKey:@"MarriageDate"];
    NSDate *marriageAnniversary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:marriageDate];
    NSData *engagedDate = [UserDefault objectForKey:@"EngagedDate"];
    NSDate *engagementAnniversary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:engagedDate];
    NSData *movedInDate = [UserDefault objectForKey:@"MovedInDate"];
    NSDate *movedInAnniversary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:movedInDate];
    NSData *inLoveDate = [UserDefault objectForKey:@"InLoveDate"];
    NSDate *inLoveAnniversary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:inLoveDate];
    NSData *startedDatingDate = [UserDefault objectForKey:@"StartedDatingDate"];
    NSDate *startedDatingAnniversary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:startedDatingDate];
    NSData *firstKissDate = [UserDefault objectForKey:@"FirstKissDate"];
    NSDate *firstKissAnniversary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:firstKissDate];
    NSData *firstMetDate = [UserDefault objectForKey:@"FirstMetDate"];
    NSDate *firstMetAnniversary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:firstMetDate];

    //////////SEE IF DATA EXISTS-IF IT DOES, LOAD IT, IF NOT LOAD STANDARD LABELS//////////
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        if ([UserDefault objectForKey:@"MarriageDate"])
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Married Since: %@",[df stringFromDate:marriageAnniversary]];
            components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                         fromDate:marriageAnniversary toDate: todaysDate options: 0];
            dayss = [components day];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have been married for %ld days!", (long)dayss];
        }
        /////////////LOAD STANDARD LABELS IF NO DATA//////////////////
        else
        {
        dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date You Got Married"];
        daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started"];
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if ([UserDefault objectForKey:@"EngagedDate"])
        {
        dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Engaged On: %@",[df stringFromDate:engagementAnniversary]];
        components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                     fromDate:engagementAnniversary toDate: todaysDate options: 0];
        dayss = [components day];
        daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Engaged %ld Days Ago!", (long)dayss];
        }
        else
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date You Got Engaged"];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started"];
        }
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        if ([UserDefault objectForKey:@"MovedInDate"])
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Moved In On: %@",[df stringFromDate:movedInAnniversary]];
            components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                         fromDate:movedInAnniversary toDate: todaysDate options: 0];
            dayss = [components day];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You first moved in together %ld days ago!", (long)dayss];
        }
        else
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date You Moved In Together"];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started"];
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        if ([UserDefault objectForKey:@"InLoveDate"])
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"In Love On: %@",[df stringFromDate:inLoveAnniversary]];
            components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                         fromDate:inLoveAnniversary toDate: todaysDate options: 0];
            dayss = [components day];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You fell in love %ld days ago!", (long)dayss];
        }
        else
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date You First Fell In Love"];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started"];
        }
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        if ([UserDefault objectForKey:@"StartedDatingDate"])
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Started Dating: %@",[df stringFromDate:startedDatingAnniversary]];
            components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                         fromDate:startedDatingAnniversary toDate: todaysDate options: 0];
            dayss = [components day];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You started dating %ld days ago!", (long)dayss];
        }
        else
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date You Started Dating"];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started"];
        }
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 5)
    {
        if ([UserDefault objectForKey:@"FirstKissDate"])
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Kiss On: %@",[df stringFromDate:firstKissAnniversary]];
            components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                         fromDate:firstKissAnniversary toDate: todaysDate options: 0];
            dayss = [components day];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You had your first kiss %ld days ago!", (long)dayss];
        }
        else
        {
            dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date Of Your First Kiss"];
            daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started"];
        }
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 6)
    {
        if ([UserDefault objectForKey:@"FirstMetDate"])
        {
        dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Met On: %@",[df stringFromDate:firstMetAnniversary]];
        components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components: NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                     fromDate:firstMetAnniversary toDate: todaysDate options: 0];
        dayss = [components day];
        daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You first met your partner %ld days ago!", (long)dayss];
        }
        else
        {
        dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date You First Met"];
        daysLeftLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started"];
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know its good practice to keep cellforrowatindexpath as uncluttered as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> #define UserDefault [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
> ```

### NO!

There's a reason that Apple didn't bring `#define` pre-processor macros into the Swift language.  Generally speaking, the primary function of these macros is to make debugging more difficult.

In almost all cases of macros, you can get the same thing with constants or functions.  Both of these allow for better, more accurate syntax highlighting, and they give an indication as to the actual return type (or depending on the macro, the argument types).

So here, if we want to shorten the `standardUserDefaults` call down slightly, we can create a function:

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults() {
    return [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}
```

But I don't really know how much value this really has.  Honestly, we should probably be calling into user defaults so infrequently that this macro should have relatively little value.

For example, you already have some redundant calls into user defaults in your existing code base, but I'd make the case that we could minimize this further.

If I've read your code correctly, we are storing seven values in user defaults, correct?  They're all dates for particular events, correct?  So why don't we stick all of these dates into a dictionary which then goes into a single key for user defaults?  So now, we only access user defaults when we need to store or retrieve our dictionary of `@"AnniversaryDates"`.

---

Throughout your code, you have big sections marked of with comments looking something like this:

> ```
> ////////////////ADD EDIT GEAR ICON TO ACCESSORY CELL VIEW//////////////////
> ```

This is a pretty clear indicator that you're already aware of how to break your method down into smaller methods.  All you have to do is simply do it.

But let's be clear... some of these things can and should be in the logic of the `SimpleTableCell` class (which probably deserves a better name).

I haven't seen the UI, but it seems like our cell has about four UI elements and an action.  Well, these UI elements can be set up in the nib.  The image for the settings button can be set in the nib.  And the action for tapping that button can be tied to the cell.  The cell can then forward that tap to whatever by whatever means (a delegate).  But importantly, for having a nib, we're doing way, way too much UI work programmatically.

---

The code for the date formatter doesn't belong in here.  I'd make a case for an `NSDateFormatter` extension.

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)anniversaryDateFormatter {
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    });
    return formatter;
}
```

And now when we need it, we're just grabbing it via a simple call:

```
[NSDateFormatter anniversaryDateFormatter];
```

---

As for this big `if`-`else` block you have, well... it simply shouldn't exist at all.

We should have proper model objects.  Something along the lines of this:

```
@interface Anniversary : NSObject

@property AnniversaryType anniversaryType;
@property NSDate *anniversaryDate;

@property (readonly) NSString *dateOfAnniversaryDescription;
@property (readonly) NSString *daysAgoDescription;

@end
```

Where `AnniversaryType` is an enumeration we define to account for the different types of anniversaries we care about in the app.

From here, we simply build out an array of these objects, and use these model objects to set up our cell:

```
Anniversary *anniversary = anniversaries[indexPath.row];
cell.dateLabel.text = anniversary.dateOfAnniversaryDescription;
cell.daysLeftLabel.text = anniversary.daysAgoDescription ?: @"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started";
```

And yes... we should either publicly expose these labels in the cell's header, or we should provide methods that allow us to set this text.  We absolutely shouldn't be hacking ourselves references to these labels using their tags as you did here:

> ```
> UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:100];
> UILabel *daysLeftLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
> ```

---

To be explicitly clear about how much of your logic should be in the method you've shared with us, if I were writing this, I'd be shooting for something about like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *reuseID = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseID];
    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:reuseID owner:self options:nil];
        cell = nib.firstObject;
    }

    Anniversary *anniversary = anniversaries[indexPath.row];
    cell.thumbnail = anniversary.thumbnail;
    cell.anniversaryDate = anniversary.dateOfAnniversaryDescription;
    cell.daysSinceAnniversary = anniversary.daysAgoDescription ?: @"Tap Gear Icon To Get Started";

    return cell;
}
```

And this is effectively how this method should look every time.  It has two parts.  The first part is the dequeuing or allocation of the necessary cell.  The second part is setting all of the cell's properties based on your model object.

Comment: The extension of NSDateFormatter, creates a shared instance that is only created once and then reused throughout the application?  I'll be straight forward with you, I have never implemented this before, and it's giving me some grief.  From my understanding the extension just has to be put under the @implementation (Class name)?

When I do this and make the call to this extension I am told that there is No Known Class Method For Selector 'anniversaryDateFormatter'.

Comment: `@implementation NSDateFormatter (AnniversaryDate)`